# TypeError: 'requestAnimationFrame' called on an object that does not implement interface Window

Tags: javascript

I am converting my `setInterval` code to `requestAnimationFrame`. I am using it inside a class so I need to bind `this` to the passed function.

When I assign the correct vendor function to a variable (`this.raf`), I am getting the error:

> TypeError: 'requestAnimationFrame' called on an object that does not
>   implement interface Window.

The code works fine when I call `window.requestAnimationFrame` directly. Any ideas why the error?

Here is [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mseifert/zfuzLpo5/)

```
slideshow = (function() {
  function slideshow() {
    this.slideShowRunning = false;
    this.slide = 0;
  }

  slideshow.prototype.startSlideshow = function() {
    var newSlide;
    this.slideShowRunning = true;
    this.rafId;
    this.raf = window.requestAnimationFrame ||
      window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
      window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
      window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
      window.oRequestAnimationFrame;

    function loop() {
      // stop the loop if fn returned false
      if (this.slideShowRunning !== false) {
        if (this.slide < this.count - 1) {
          newSlide = this.slide + 1;
        }
        this.loadSlide(newSlide);
        // loop until cancelled
        var boundLoop = loop.bind(this);

        // THIS GIVES THE ERROR
        this.rafId = this.raf(boundLoop);

        // BUT THIS WORKS
        //this.rafId = window.requestAnimationFrame(boundLoop);
      }
    }
    var boundLoop = loop.bind(this);
    boundLoop();
  }

  slideshow.prototype.loadSlide = function(slideNumber) {
    // loading the slide
    console.log(slideNumber);
  }

  return slideshow;

})();

ss = new slideshow();
divStart = document.getElementById("start");
divStart.onclick = function() {
  ss.startSlideshow()
};
```

Comment: Why are you assigning it to `this`? Just set `var raf = …;` (in the IIFE’s scope) and call `raf(boundLoop);`. Anyway, the issue is because the `this` a function runs with is set when it’s called: `x.raf()` will set `this` to `x` in the function `x.raf` refers to. `requestAnimationFrame` doesn’t expect its `this` to be your object. Also, `this.rafId;` does nothing as a statement.

Comment: @Ryan - Your explanation was what I expected. Your solution is too simple. Fortunately there is no reason to have it set to a class var. Thanks for the quick answer and the solution.